# Apache2 wildcard not showing the correct DocumentRoot

Tags: apache, apache2

For some reason my apache2 server is showing me the contents of another virtualhost instead of the wildcard virtualhost.

When I enter hello.purecore.io, the apache2 server shows me the contents from api.purecore.io, when it should show another folder.

The virtualhost config for my wildcard domain is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/wildcard.purecore.io
  ServerName wildcard.purecore.io
  ServerAlias *.purecore.io
</VirtualHost>
```

And it is saved as "00_wildcard.purecore.io.conf",
The virtualhost of api.purecore.io is

```
<VirtualHost api.purecore.io:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/api.purecore.io/
        ServerName api.purecore.io
        ServerAdmin quiquelhappy@purecore.io
</VirtualHost>
```

and it is saved as api.purecore.io.conf. So,

1. when entering any random subdomain other than api.purecore.io, it should load the contents from /var/www/wildcard.purecore.io,
2. when accessing api.purecore.io, it should load the contents from /var/www/api.purecore.io/

but for some reason, when accessing a random domain, it shows the contents of /var/www/api.purecore.io/ too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache processes the `<VirtualHost>` sections in order they are read.  So the first one read here is `00_wildcard.purecore.io.conf`, then `api.purecore.io.conf`.

But the line `ServerAlias *.purecore.io` includes domain `api.purecore.io`, so it uses the configuration from that VirtualHost.

Solution, rename your files to ensure the proper order.  You want to put the most restrictive VirtualHost first, the wildcard ones after.

```
mv 00_wildcard.purecore.io.conf 01_wildcard.purecore.io.conf
mv api.purecore.io.conf 00_api.purecore.io.conf
```

And restart (or graceful).

FYI 1: the first VirtualHost is always the default if Apache cannot find another VirtualHost definition that matches the request.

FYI 2: no need for `<VirtualHost api.purecore.io:80>`, put `<VirtualHost *:80>`, the order is the solution here.

Comment: thank you! I was trying to to just the opposite! :)